# Is it possible to use XP visual styles (*.msstyles) or Windows Blinds in a thinapp portable application?

Tags: virtualization, portable, deployment

It's been a while since I made a portable (Office 2007) [Thinapp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) application, and since then I've uninstalled VMWare from my machine to free up space, so I'd like to know if someone already knows the answer to this before I set up everything again to try it.

I'm thinking of installing a visual style ([*.msstyles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSSTYLES), for XP) along with the application to thinapp before post-setup capture. Failing that, maybe I'll try with visual mods such as [Windows Blinds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WindowBlinds). The purpose is *to be able to run a portable application with a specific visual style*.

**So my question is:**

Is it possible? (I believe it somehow is, since [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) does [something similar](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12309/install-xp-mode-with-virtualbox-using-the-vmlite-plugin/) to [XP Mode](https://i.imgur.com/WjSrO.jpg))

If it is, will it work on a computer with the "classic" Windows style?
If it's not, will it work with another virtualization software? ([Xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/)?)
If it's not possible with *.msstyles, will it work with visual mods such as Windows Blinds?

(P.S.: Awfully tagged due to lack of relevant tags or 100+ rep to create a tag :P)

Comment: So you want to know if the Thinapp's visual style is affected by the host OS's visual style?

Comment: Yes, that's what normally happens, but I want to override that behaviour by telling it to virtualize the Visual Style as well.